# php mysql update and delete won't take effect on home.php

Tags: php, mysql

How will I make the $UpdateQuery and $DeleteQuery function work I already typed these codes in order to function but there are no changes made in the home.php file??

these are the codes in the update.php:
[[this is my database used named ruiz with the table 'registry']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmmdC.jpg)

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['update'])){

$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE registry SET db_id = '$_POST[db_id]', db_name = '$_POST[db_name]', db_age = '$_POST[db_age]', db_gender = '$_POST[db_gender]', db_birthdate = '$_POST[db_birthdate]', db_phone = '$_POST[db_phone]', db_address = '$_POST[db_address]' 
                WHERE db_id = '$_POST[hidden]'";
                mysqli_query(UpdateQuery);

        //redirect to home.php
        header('Location: home.php');

            }

            $query= mysqli_query( $DB,"SELECT * FROM registry" );

        echo"<h2><center>Employee Masterlist</center></h2>";
        echo "<table class = \"form\" border = \"1\" cellspacing = \"3\">";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Employee ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Age</th>";
        echo "<th>Gender</th>";
        echo "<th>Birthdate </th>";
        echo "<th>Phone No. </th>";
        echo "<th>Address </th>";
        echo "</tr>";


            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query))
            {
                    echo "<form action=update.php method=post>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text name=db_id 
                    value=" . $row['db_id'] . "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text name=db_name 
                    value=" . $row['db_name'] . "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text name=db_age 
                    value=" . $row['db_age'] . "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text 
                    name=db_gender value=" . $row['db_gender']. "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text 
                    name=db_birthdate value=" . $row['db_birthdate'] . ">   
                        </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text 
                    name=db_phone value=" . $row['db_phone'] . "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input id=input-up type=text 
                    name=db_address value=" . $row['db_address'] . ">
                    </td>";
                    echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . 
                    $row['db_id'] . "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input class=send_btn type=submit 
                    name=update value=Update". "> </td>"; 
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</form>";

            }
            }
            echo"</table>";
                ?>  
                    </div>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

these are the codes in the delete.php same with the previous database, ruiz with the table 'registry'

```
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['delete'])){

$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM registry WHERE db_id = '$_POST[hidden]'";
mysqli_query($DeleteQuery);

//redirect to home.php
header('Location: home.php');

            }       

            $query= mysqli_query( $DB,"SELECT * FROM registry" );


        echo"<h2><center>Employee Masterlist</center></h2>
        <table class = \"form\" border = \"1\" cellspacing = \"3\">
        <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Birthdate </th>
        <th>Phone No. </th>
        <th>Address </th>
        </tr>";


            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query))
            {
                    echo "<form action=delete.php method=post>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_age']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_gender']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_birthdate']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_phone']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['db_address']."</td>";
                    echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['db_id'] . "> </td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<input class=send_btn type=submit name=delete value=Delete". "> </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</form>";

            }
                }
            echo"</table>";
?>
```

Comment: And what is your question? (Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34289509/edit) your question to include what you've tried and what's going on; it's not enough to have the question _only_ in the title!)

Comment: sorry about that hehe

Comment: At this point I don't see where you connect to your database. I only see queries you try to execute, did you leave it out on purpose?

Did you do any debugging?

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script in each page. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Also, inspect the table using the browser's web development tools. Are the forms where you expect them to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
$delete_id = $_GET['del'];

$query = "delete from users where id='$delete_id'";

if(mysql_query($query)){
echo
"<script>
window.open('home.php')
</script>";
}
```

try like this and respond to me if it worked or you any problem

Comment: and in update section you have written db_id in two times . check it that also